# Android Admob test are not being displayed in my phone

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

This is the first time i am trying to implement ads on my app i am following this guide [google Developers](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#load_the_ad_in_the_mainactivity_class) from google developers itself and i had done everything as been mentioned in the guide and even added the internet permission
in the android manifest which had not been mentioned in the guide.As you can see the below image.

[image]

Ads by google is displayed at the end of the activity but when i run the app in my phone as shown in the below image.

[image]

The ads are nowhere to be seen in my activity.I followed each and every step properly as been mention in the guide again and again also,but coudn't figure it out.

EDIT-I checked the logcat and it's showing the following errors.
03-18 00:23:32.652 2698-2710/com.example.kanna.micromaxunite2_thecompleteguide W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
03-18 00:23:32.661 2698-2698/com.example.kanna.micromaxunite2_thecompleteguide W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0

Thank you.

Comment: add your code so we can understand easily

Comment: There are around 4 to 5 files wher the code has to be added so i thought it would look a bit messier and every single coded i added was just from the google Developers page itself not even slightly modified.so it wont be a problem i guess and i had checked the logcat and it is showing the following errors-03-17 23:17:20.738 5105-5119/com.example.kanna.micromaxunite2_thecompleteguide W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
03-17 23:17:20.739 5105-5105/com.example.kanna.micromaxunite2_thecompleteguide W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0

Comment: Have you create admob account. ?

Comment: And try this link. http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-how-to-integrate-google-admob-in-your-app/

Comment: @ArpitPatel i don't want to get in trouble using my own ads at the developing stage itself so that i may unfortunatly click it  and may get suspended so i am using the googles test ads and not to make it any fault i even tried using my own banner add id also and the same happens..

Comment: Thank you bro,Now i had found that the ads are not being displayed only in my phone and in other phones it is displaying fine so,I use a custom ROM and i think the developer had installed some kind of add blockers in my phone?? and if so yes do you have any idea how to identify them and uninstall them.